# Mat Chip List opon selection expands input

Tags: javascript, css, angular, typescript, angular-material

Giving the default behavior, when value is selected from a dropdown, MatChip appears within the input, but also expands it. I am a bit surprised this is the default behavior. Anyone can suggest how they fix it? Providing a forked StackBlitz demo (source take from Angular Material documentation):

[**DEMO**](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-3eveow?file=src%2Fapp%2Fchips-autocomplete-example.html)

You can see in the images bellow - when chip selected, input becomes taller.

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Problem

The problem is `mat-form-field-infix` class. When there are **chips** in the input, they increase the height.

## Solution

You can set the minimal height for that class to be the same as when there are **chips** in the input. You can do it in the CSS file like this:

```css
::ng-deep .mat-form-field-infix {
  min-height: 32px;
}
```

[Working example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-3eveow-hhunk9?file=src/app/chips-autocomplete-example.css)